# Gaps in a proof: One question or several ones?

Tags: discussion

I need to fill gaps in a proof by another person. The proving is preferred by references to theorems in "Stone spaces" book.

Should I ask it as one question or as several questions (for individual gaps).

One reason to prefer ask by one question is that I may misunderstood the gaps in the proof and thus receive guidance.

Comment: As a general rule, one question per problem you face. I think it should apply in this case.

Comment: I don't think there is a completely universal rule that will apply here. We generically prefer one question per post. We also like posts to be self-contained, and sometimes it may be excessive to have many tiny questions. If there is a self-contained first gap that you're concerned with, perhaps you should ask that and hope that an improved understanding of that gap will help you proceed. If not, then ask the next self-contained bit afterwards.

Comment: I think that, as mixedmath says, one rule of thumb is to just ask *one* typical question first, edited to have as much context and motivation as possible. Then see if the answers to that question allow you to answer other questions you had without additional help, and only make additional posts for other questions that bring up new issues. It would be ideal to wait for some time before asking follow-up questions, say 48 hours, to give people a chance to answer the original question.  Multiple similar questions posted simultaneously are not better than one post full of numerous questions.

Comment: Above all, keep in mind that this site is for *questions* that you have about mathematics, not for "please fill in this gap for me" posts.  Just the fact that there is a gap in a proof is not a complete question - your thoughts about how to fill the gap are what make the actual question for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the Question is well researched and formulated, I would likely consider an issue of two or three apparent gaps in one proof as allowed in a single question considered as "closely related" multiple parts.  See the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for closed questions, which adjures us not to ask multiple "distinct" questions.

My thought is that clarifying the reasoning/justification in one step *may* be likely to have an effect on filling what the OP considers a later gap, so that it might be anticipated that a combined presentation is expeditious, even if the OP is not able to articulate a suspicion that this should be expected.